Combine multiple conditions for finding elements in nested tuple
Python novice here.
I have the following nested tuple containing values, sides and context:
my_tuple = [(121, 131, 174, 188, 228, 242, 282),
 ('Left', 'Right', 'Right', 'Left', 'Left', 'Right', 'Right'),
 ('Foot Strike',
  'Foot Off',
  'Foot Strike',
  'Foot Off',
  'Foot Strike',
  'Foot Off',
  'Foot Strike')]

I would like to extract the values which agree with 'Right' AND 'Foot Strike' (i.e. val = 174 & 282).
I know I could extract the first indices of all subtuples by using
first = [lis[0] for lis in my_tuple]

and subsequently select the first vaule of that tuple, but I am failing to correctly set conditional values to go with this selection.
Thank your for helping out the newbie!

out = [p for p, *s in zip(*my_tuple)  if ' '.join(s) == 'Right Foot Strike']

out = (el[0] for el in zip(*my_tuple) if el[1]=='Right' and el[2]=='Foot Strike')

Explanation:
First, we use zip to obtain iterable of (value, side, context) tuples.
Then we can go through that iterable, filter on our condition and return first element of each tuple.
Output:
print(list(out))
[174, 282]


Thanks! So many things left to learn...

We don't often see this syntax for list comprehension. Please use brackets [...] rather than list(...)
